# Why is the data being logged 4 times?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm using redux and hooks. I want to get data from redux. It's coming but 4 times. I think this situation is bug. How to fix? Is incorrect method i was use.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { getProductDetail } from '../../redux/actions/products/productActions'

function ProductDetail({
    product,
    getProductDetail,
    history,
    ...props
}) {

    const productId = props.match.params.productSlug

     useEffect(() => {
        getProductDetail(productId)
    }, [])


    console.log(product)


    return (
        <>

        </>
    )
}


const mapStateToProps = state =>({
    product: state.productDetailReducer
});

const mapDisptachToProps = {
    getProductDetail
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDisptachToProps)(ProductDetail)
```

Comment: If "coming but 4 times" just means it `console.log`s 4 times, then its not a bug. It just renders 4 times.

Comment: double html is incoming when i render page .

Comment: The code in the question renders nothing. Your problem must be somewhere else or the code in question is incomplete

Comment: Yes i know there isn't rendering . when i write {product} in fragment. It's rendering 4 times.

Comment: Your description of the problem should match the code in the question, it makes it really hard to help when not all of the pieces are present. For starters, I think the place where you render `ProductDetails` and the reducer for `productDetailReducer` would be useful pieces in debugging this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your useEffect should only run on mount, but it's good practice to restrict it to run when there are changes to its variables.

```
useEffect(() => {
    getProductDetail(productId)
}, [productId])
```